# Insert new line after two words

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a text area which is filled from database. In that textarea comma's are replaced by white space using this.

```
 document.getElementById('<%=fnl000Db000MESSAGE.ClientId %>').value=document.getElementById('<%=fnl000Db000MESSAGE.ClientId %>').value.replace(/,/g,'\s');
```

Now I want to insert a new a new line after first two words like this..
eg.. hello admin '\n' welcome

how can i get this using javascript. Do i need to use Regex or any other way.

I want an output like 
Hello Admin
Process are running...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't all fancy like a regex, but I find it easier to read =).

http://jsfiddle.net/Pfx3P/

```
var foo = 'Hello Admin Process are running....';
var secondSpaceIndex = foo.indexOf(' ', foo.indexOf(' ') + 1);
var foo2 = foo.substr(0,secondSpaceIndex) + '\n' + foo.substr(secondSpaceIndex + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
"hello admin welcome".replace(/^(\w+\s+\w+)/, '$1\n');
```

EDIT:

The regex satisfies your requirement, which is to match the first two words, regardless of the number of spaces or the length of the words. Another approach, which is a bit more flexible in that you can specify the number of words to match would be

```
"hello admin welcome".replace(/^(([\w]+\s+){2})/, '$1\n');
```

Comment: admin is like a user name it may change.

Comment: His works with different names too. It's a good answer as far as I can tell. http://jsfiddle.net/Pfx3P/1/

Comment: @JayaPrakashRokkam The regex matches the first two words. You can replace admin with any word and it will work.